# excel file column data modify or find and replace with a pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file which has hundreds of emails in the first column, like this:

```
Ameerali Uncle. <seenameer@gmail.com>
Afkaar (Habeeb). <afkar.mam@gmail.com>
Ameerali Uncle. <seenameer@gmail.com>
```

I wanted to break this from <> sign and put it in to a new column and leave the first column with just name. So after doing this, it will be like:

```
column 1         column 2
Afkaar (Habeeb)  afkar.mam@gmail.com
```

How can i easily get this done with the help of any online tool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would auto-filter by the "@" symbol, select visible cells only, copy/paste into a new sheet and use find/replace for the "<" and ">" symbols. Then go back to original sheet, highlight the already selected cells yellow, filter by no fill, select visible cells and copy/paste into the other sheet. This will only work if each name has an email and vice versa.

Comment: Should we copy and past it manually or what ? can u tell me hw is it possible to auto filter is it in start menu or edit or where ?

Comment: For Excel 2007+, Filter is in the Data tab, click it and you will see a drop drown arrow in your column header. Click it and type in the @ symbol in the little box that pops up. After that, select the cells it gives you using Ctrl+Shift+Down. Ctrl+G, Special, Visible Cells Only will select them for you to copy and paste.

Answer (score -1):

simply use Data -> Text-to-data with delimiter '. '(dot space)

Comment: That addresses half of the question.  What about getting rid of the <>?

Comment: 2 simple replace operations should do the job